# Why does the javascript's .toUpperCase function include numbers?

Tags: javascript

When I put numbers in my "password", there is no uppercase error message. HELP!!! You can ignore most of the code. My question is why when I put numbers in the password the console doesn't log "Incorrect password. Please put a uppercase letter."
(Where you type the password is in the last line of the code) Thanks for helping!

```
var specialCharacters = ["!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", 
"[", "]"];

function isPasswordValid(input) {
if (hasUpperCase(input) && hasLowercase(input) && isLongEnough(input) &&  hasSpecialCharacter(input)) {
console.log("The password is valid.");
}

if (!hasUpperCase(input)) {
console.log("Incorrect password. Please put a uppercase letter.");
}

if (!hasLowercase(input)) {
console.log("Incorrect password. Please put a lowercase letter.");
}

if (!isLongEnough(input)) {
console.log("Incorrect password. Please increase the length of your password to 8 characters.");
}

if (!hasSpecialCharacter(input)) {
console.log("Incorrect password. Please put a special character.");
}
}

function hasUpperCase(input) {
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
if (input[i] === input[i].toUpperCase()) {
  return true;
}
}
}

function hasLowercase(input) {
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
if (input[i] === input[i].toLowerCase()) {
  return true;
}
}
}

function isLongEnough(input) {
if (input.length >= 8) {
return true;
}
}

function hasSpecialCharacter(input) {
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
for (var j = 0; j < specialCharacters.length; j++) {
  if (input[i] === specialCharacters[j]) {
    return true;
  }
}
}
}

isPasswordValid("");
```

Comment: The input is probably a string, so the number is really a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input is a string. And if you use the `toUpperCase()` method against it, it will **ignore the numbers**, and just convert the lower case letters/characters to upper case.

Answer (score 0):

*"there is no uppercase error message"* Because you aren't checking for a upper case letter, you are just testing string equality.

```
"1" == "1".toUpperCase()
```

`toUpperCase()` does not strip out numbers or other non-letter characters.

If you want to to test for a upper case letter, actually test for an uppercase letter.

You can use a [regular expression test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) to do this:

```
if( !(/[A-Z]/).test(input[i]) ){
    //No uppercase letters found
}
```

`[A-Z]` tells the expression to look for a character within the provided character set (in this case capital A through capital Z)

Answer (score 0):

try to add more if parameter for if statement like this ()

```js
function hasUpperCase(input) {
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i] === input[i].toUpperCase() && isNaN(parseInt(input[i]))) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```